# Asp.net MVC4 Razor syntax error

Tags: razor

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteNote(@note.id)" />
```

There are 2 syntax error on the above code, the error points to **(@note.id)**

But I do not know how to fix that error.

And It  does not make any error for compiling and running.

How should I fix that error?

Comment: how's that possible: "There are 2 syntax error" and "It does not make any error for compiling and running"?

Comment: Oh I mean, it shows only in visual studio 2012.

Comment: I find that VS sometimes reports markup errors that really are not errors.